# Shut up a kernel error or avoid it by configuring Prometheus Node Exporter

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus-exporter

Let me start by giving the output which I get to see in `/var/log/syslog` and with `dmesg`:

```
[559151.898586] ACPI Error: SMBus/IPMI/GenericSerialBus write requires Buffer of length 66, found length 32 (20170831/exfield-427)
[559151.911578] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PMM]
[559151.911580] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PMM]
[559151.911584] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed \_SB.PMI0._PMM, AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT (20170831/psparse-550)
[559151.916648] ACPI Exception: AE_AML_BUFFER_LIMIT, Evaluating _PMM (20170831/power_meter-338)
```

Clearly the [Prometheus Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) is *triggering* the error, although it *doesn't seem to be the cause* for the error that gets logged.

Now what I want to achieve is - preferably - to tell the Prometheus Node Exporter to stop querying for whatever information it's attempting to query. Failing that, I'd like to silence these messages so they don't spam my log files.

How would I go about either of these options? ... or perhaps there are other options I haven't considered ...

This is happening on Ubuntu 18.04 with the packaged `prometheus-node-exporter` (it also happened with the 0.16 and 0.17 versions of `prometheus-node-exporter` which could be installed via `stretch-backports` - yes, on Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the best method is to blacklist the kernel module named `acpi_power_meter` by adding a line as follows into `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` (or a newly created file in that same folder):

```
blacklist acpi_power_meter
```

On a running system one should also run `rmmod acpi_power_meter` as super user in order to unload the module. I already tested it and this works perfectly fine on all the HP servers I am taking care of. Cause of the error is allegedly a BIOS defect on said HP hardware.

This seems the only viable method and I found it via [this comment](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter/issues/903#issuecomment-381676350) on the Prometheus `node_exporter` project.

Answer (score 1):

I had these `[_PMM]` type log messages in a new `openvz` container (so the messages were outside of my control).

With `rsyslog` you can create a **property filter**  in `/etc/rsyslog.d/discard.conf` (files in this directory are sourced before all other configuration is applied):

```
:msg, contains, "[_PMM]"    ~
```

For a `syslog` without filters (e.g inetutils-syslogd) - a simple fix is to create `/etc/cron.hourly/pmmlog` & make it executable:

```
#!/bin/sh

# remove annoying logs
# Nov 29 12:55:29 vzbackup vmunix: [161167.516267] No Arguments are initialized for method [_PMM]
# Nov 29 12:56:29 vzbackup vmunix: [161227.527169] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_PMM]

sed -i '/.*[_PMM]/d' /var/log/messages
```

Comment: At the very least on my Ubuntu machine I cannot find any cron job containing `pmm` or named this way ... also no other files in `/var/spool` and `/etc` containing that string. So apparently _that_ is not the solution to my problem. Still, thank you for taking the time to answer. Perhaps it helps someone else.

Comment: you could also run `crontab -e` as `root` & just add the `sed` line above to the `root` crontab - or you create the cron file as shown above.